# Tomcat to talk to proxy server

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy

I have an application deployed on tomcat in linux rhel 5 , now this application makes an external call to internet and my server is behind the proxy server , now how do I configure the tomcat server for it to understand the proxy.

Is there a configuration I can do to redirect all requests send by tomcat to external servers

Also to mention that I did make the entries into catalina.properties

http.proxyHost=

http.proxyPort=8080

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, configure them as VM parameters in catalina.bat.

-Dhttp.proxyHost=<> -DproxyPort=8080

Another approach would be to configure them at the application level. If you are using java's own api to invoke external url, the proxy could be set as follows. In case you are using another library like apache httpclient, it provides methods to configure the proxy.

```
    SocketAddress proxyAddress = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.HTTP, proxyAddress);

    URL url = new URL(externalURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

Comment: I tried using the same in catalina.sh as I am using linux env.  This is a 3rd party app i am using so I cant really chnage the code. Is there anyhting i can do in tomcat or web server